# iOS7 Custom UTI

Tags: ios, ios7, uti

I'm banging my head against the wall on this one, but just can't seem to make my custom UTI work.

I am working to get AirDrop implemented in my app, so I can share files between devices. Im able to successfully transfer the file(s) the other devices, but the other devices which have my app installed just will not open the files in my app.

Here is the dump from my app.plist:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>MYAPP</string>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>57x57</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>MYAPPNAME Shared Assignment</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.MYAPPNAME.SIAASSIGNMENT</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>57x57 2.png</string>
                <string>114x114 2.png</string>
                <string>72x72 2.png</string>
                <string>144x144 2.png</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.MYAPPNAME.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>4.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>4.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>Main_Window</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
    <string>Main_Window_iPad</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarTintParameters</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UINavigationBar</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Style</key>
            <string>UIBarStyleDefault</string>
            <key>Translucent</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.text</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>MYAPPNAME Shared Assignment</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.MYAPPNAME.SIAASSIGNMENT</string>
            <key>UTTypeSize320IconFile</key>
            <string>72x72</string>
            <key>UTTypeSize64IconFile</key>
            <string>57x57</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>com.MYAPPNAME.SIAASSIGNMENT</key>
                <array>
                    <string>SIAASSIGNMENT</string>
                                <key>public.mime-type</key>
                                <string>application/xml</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have tried many different things to make this work, I just can't seem to get iOS7 to recognize that this is my file type. I know that you are not supposed to use the 'public.xxx' namespaces for your UTIs as those are pre assigned by Apple.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried setting it's type to something not public.*?

Comment: Do you mean do not use public.text, but something else?

Comment: Yes, just as an experiment to see if that has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it now, no luck :(

Comment: Here are some images of what the UI in XCode5 shows: [link](http://imgur.com/l86wOZh,gtJowhe#0)

Comment: I just realized you have a type export section, but no type import. You'll need to [declare that you import](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html) that type as well, for the receiving app to get the data.

Comment: This is the sound of my hand hitting my forehead! I'll try that, Thanks!

Comment: @RyanR If you declare a UTI as exported, must you also declare it as imported? The [UTI doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH204-SW2) mentions: If both imported and exported declarations for a UTI exist, the exported declaration takes precedence over imported one.

Comment: @DenVog as the doc you linked says, the import and export have different intentions, so I would think they are both required. If that is the case, the order of precedence would apply to things like the icon, filename extension, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you [declare the types as imported](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html) so that iOS knows to display your app as an option to open them.

Also, make sure you implement [-application:openUrl:sourceApplication:annotation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aopenURL%3asourceApplication%3aannotation%3a) to receive files through AirDrop or a document interaction controller.

Comment: So this is what did the trick for me, but I also had to change UTTypeTagSpecification node from "com.MYAPPNAME.SIAASSIGNMENT" to "public.filename-extension" as it says to do in the link you provided.